How to programmatically test if a website has disabled right-click?
I am doing a task which requires me to find some websites that have their right-click disabled, and I want to write a simply Python script to scan a list of websites to find some samples. As there are many ways to disable right-click, I wonder if there is any way where I can use scripts to test if a website has right-click disabled?

This sounds like an XY Problem.  What are you really trying to do?  That is, if you found a website that disabled right-click (or intercepted right-click with their own handler), what would you do with it?

Oh, nothing special. I ran into some websites, e.g., e-commerce, artists, etc, and find some disabled the right-click, supposedly to disallow copying of the images. Out of curiosity, I want to find more samples and see what sites commonly disable right-click, which then spurs me to think how can I write a script to find such websites.

"As there are many ways to disable right-click" - are there really?

The only thing you can do is to load the page, run its javascript, fire a right click event, and see whether its default action (opening the browser context menu) is prevented.

The dispatchEvent method will return true if the event hasn't been canceled and false otherwise.
You can thus fire an Event whose name is "contextmenu" with a cancelable flag and check the return value, (or the defaultPrevented property of the fired Event object).


const test = () => dispatchEvent(new Event("contextmenu", { cancelable: true }));

console.log("before blocking:", test());

addEventListener("contextmenu", (evt) => evt.preventDefault());

console.log("after blocking:", test());



But this would tell only if such an event handler was added on the window. It seems it's quite common to also use an ugly <body oncontextmenu="return false"> attribute event (don't do that please), and it is also very probable that only a few elements have their contextmenu disabled.
To catch these, you'll want to fire your event deeper in the tree, or at least on the target element, and with a bubbles flag to catch them.
Below is an example code telling you if any element has its contextmenu disabled. It will fire a bubbling event to all the leaf-elements in the tree (below the <body>) and stop at the first match. With a bit more work you could modify it to climb back to where the events where actually added, but that seem an overkill for this question.


// Now be bubble up the tree
const isMenuBlocked = (target) => !target.dispatchEvent(new Event("contextmenu", { cancelable: true, bubbles: true }));

// We could make it way more performant by using a TreeWalker
// but for a one shot, simplicity wins
const leaves = [...document.body.querySelectorAll("*:not(:has(*))")];

console.log("before blocking:", leaves.some((elem) => isMenuBlocked(elem)));

document.querySelector(".target").setAttribute("oncontextmenu", "return false");

console.log("after blocking:", leaves.some((elem) => isMenuBlocked(elem)));
<div>
  <span>You can right-click me</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="target"><i>But You can't right-click me</i></span>
</div>



